# Php - checkbox to multiply values of dropdown options?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to multiply the values of a dropdown list with a checkbox?

Let's say that I have a selection of 300 usd, then when I check the checkbox, it will act as a multiplier, so the value will change from 300 to 600 uds.

Here is the site: www.stanleyproductions.dk/pbr/pbr.html

I have no idea how php works, I only know some html so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if that's the case then you'll need to learn basic php first, you can do input submissions and arithmetic and some stuff

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the time for it. That's why I bought that template in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per what I understand,there is no need of PHP.

You only need HTML and javascript.

```
    <select id="pkg" onchange="calculate_total()">
    <option disabled selected value="0">Select packege</option>
    <option value="1">10</option>
    <option value="2">20</option>
    <option value="3">30</option>
    <option value="4">40</option>
</select>
<br>
<b>With extra </b>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="calculate_total()" id="extra1" value="50">graphics
<br>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="calculate_total()" id="extra2" value="100">underlay Music
<br>
<br>
<b><u>Total</u></b>
<br>
<span id="total_value"></span>
<script>
    function calculate_total() {
        var final_cost = 0;
        //get select box option
        pkg_option = parseInt(document.getElementById("pkg").value);
        //get extra package checkbox

        //graphics
        if (document.getElementById("extra1").checked) {
            final_cost = parseInt(final_cost) + (parseInt(document.getElementById("extra1").value) * pkg_option);
        }

        //music
        if (document.getElementById("extra2").checked) {
            final_cost = parseInt(final_cost) + (parseInt(document.getElementById("extra2").value) * pkg_option);
        }

        document.getElementById("total_value").innerHTML = final_cost;
    }
</script>
```

This is simple to understand.Change as per your requirment.

Comment: That's just what I needed! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: PHP for server side scripting and as your requirement,no need of it (and reduce load from server ).HTML & javascript is sufficient.  @ Mikkel Stanley Nielsen accept  answer if it useful or solved your problem